# No matching function for call

Tags: c++

I've been getting this error, and I can't figure out how to fix it:

```
btree.tem:98:   instantiated from 'std::pair<typename btree<T>::iterator, bool> btree<T>::insert(const T&) [with T = char]'
test.cpp:13:   instantiated from here
btree.tem:37: error: no matching function for call to 'btree<char>::addElem(std::_List_iterator<node<char>*>&, node<char>*&)'
btree.h:178: note: candidates are: void btree<T>::addElem(std::_List_iterator<node<T>*>&, node<T>&) [with T = char]
btree.tem:98:   instantiated from 'std::pair<typename btree<T>::iterator, bool> btree<T>::insert(const T&) [with T = char]'
test.cpp:13:   instantiated from here
btree.tem:48: error: no matching function for call to 'btree<char>::addElem(std::_List_iterator<node<char>*>&, node<char>*&)'
```

Inside my header file I have this setter function:

```
void addElem (std::_List_iterator<node<T>*>& itr, node <T>& n) {
  neighbours.insert(itr, n); 
}
```

and I don't know what's wrong with it. The error seems to happen whenever I call it like this:

```
class list < node<T>* >::iterator itr = bt->level().begin();
node <T>*n = new node<T>(elem, bt->max());
bt->addElem(itr, n);
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Make your life a little easier and use typedefs. You will love yourself more for doing this. Beyond that, examine your code. You're getting a type mismatch somewhere. Look at what the function takes, and look as what your function calls are returning. Are they congruent? For instance, std::vector<int> is not the same type as std::vector<double>.

Comment: Why are you using `std::_List_iterator` ? That's an internal implementation detail.

Comment: @K-ballo I was trying it out, because I'm not sure how to pass the iterator into the `addElem` function

Comment: A `list` `iterator` to `node<T>*` would be `list< node<T>* >::iterator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is looking for:

```
btree<char>::addElem(std::_List_iterator<node<char>*>&, node<char>*&)
```

But it only found something for:

```
btree<char>::addElem(std::_List_iterator<node<char>*>&, node<char>&)
```

You're passing a pointer to your function. You've not defined an `addElem` that takes a pointer as its last argument.

Comment: If my answer didn't help you solve the issue, you should not accept it. Did you figure it out?

Comment: yeah i figured it out, thanks! it was a typo error with the list iterator

Answer (score 0):

`n` is a pointer, so you have to write this:

```
bt->addElem(itr, *n);
```

It is clear from the error message:

```
 btree.tem:37: error: no matching function for call to 
'btree<char>::addElem(std::_List_iterator<node<char>*>&, node<char>*&)'   

 btree.h:178: note: candidates are: 
 void btree<T>::addElem(std::_List_iterator<node<T>*>&, node<T>&) [with T = char]
```

See the second parameter type in the error, as well as in the suggested candidates.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not "instatiated from..." - that's the context describing which template instantiations lead to the error.

The error is

```
btree.tem:37: error: no matching function for call to 
'btree<char>::addElem(std::_List_iterator<node<char>*>&, node<char>*&)'
```

And a candidate is listed:

```
note: candidates are: 
void btree<T>::addElem(std::_List_iterator<node<T>*>&, node<T>&) 
[with T = char]
```

So it is expecting a `node<char>`, not a pointer `node<char>*`.